# Is there a difference in doing class Forward Declaration at the definition inside the class and outside the class

Tags: c++, forward-declaration

Example class `B` header:

```
class A;

class B {
   protected:
   A* Foo;
};
```

VS

```
class B {
   protected:
   class A* Foo;
};
```

What is the difference between the two class forward declarations and/or which one is preferred?

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference but the first approach is preferable because it makes the code more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Those are two examples of an [elaborate type specifier](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/elaborated_type_specifier) and they achieve the same.

As Vlad mentions in his answer, the first example ((3) on cppreference) is the common way to forward declare types and is probably understood by more developers than the other option.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference between those two, but most people prefer the first since it makes the scope of `A` obvious.

Note that there is a huge difference between these two:

```
class B {
   class A* Foo;
};

class C {
   class A;
   A* Foo;
};
```

which declares a class `A` inside the scope of `C`, and that is not the same `A` as in `B`.